# Get raw SAML assertion form KentorIT-authservices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I try get raw SAML assetion (XML) in KentorIT-authservices SampleOwinApplication.

I tried these solutions:

**Solution 1**

In Startup ConfigureAuth added:

```
 FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SaveBootstrapContext = true;
```

Access to the token:

```
    var icp = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

    var claimsIdentity = icp.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

    var ctx = claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;

    var token = ctx.SecurityToken;
```

But BootstrapContext is null.

**Solution 2**

I set on SpOptions:

```
spOptions.SystemIdentityModelIdentityConfiguration.SaveBootstrapContext = true;
```

When I debug in class `Saml2PSecurityTokenHandler` in method `CreateClaims` is set identity.BootstrapContext. This is OK.

But when I try access to token for example from HomeController BootstrapContext is null.

```
    var claimsIdentity = icp.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

    var ctx = claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;

    var token = ctx.SecurityToken;
```

Thank